# run individual test intelliJ 2016 premium with python plugin

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I know that you can right click on a test and run that individual test for Pycharm -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-tests.html

I am unable how to figure this out for IntelliJ 2016 with the python plugin?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point is to set Python SDK. It seems that you specified it thus not sure what else could be wrong. I would advice to update to latest version of Intellij IDEA and Python Plugin and see if that helps. Check also that your Project Structure -> Project SDK has correct path to Python.

Comment: yup updated to the latest version of intelliJ and I am able to run tests individually, thanks!

Comment: Good that it helped!